# How to remove the first 8 characters from specific columns of pandas dfs without knowing the colnames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that is created by the following:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"imdbPage": emptyWebPageSet,
                       "title": emptySetTitle,
                       "genre1": lst1,
                       "genre2": lst2,
                       "genre3": lst3,
                       "genre4": lst4,
                       "info":infoSet,
                       "Runtime(mins)":movieTime,
                       "releaseData":releaseDateSet,
                       "imdbRating":ratingSet,
                       "numberOfVotes":votesList,
                       "numberOfEpisodes":noOfEpisodesSet,
                       "TotalRunTime(mins)":totalRunTimeSet
                       })
df = pandas.get_dummies(data=df, columns=['genre1', 'genre2', 'genre3', 'genre4'])
```

The column titles from the output look like this:

```
output = ["imdbPage", "title", "info", "Runtime(mins)", "releaseData", "imdbRating", "numberOfVotes",
"numberOfEpisodes", """genre1_Action", "genre1_Adventure", "genre1_Animation",
"genre1_Biography", "genre1_Comedy".... etc]
```

What I want to do is remove all the `"genre1_"`, `"genre2_"` parts from the output, but I obviously don't know exactly the name of the column or how many there are — only that they start with `"genre1_"`, `"genre2_"`, `"genre3_"`, or `"genre4_"`.

Comment: Maybe you should not remove `genre1_`, etc., because they may contain useful information about order or the importance of the genres of each movie. If you insist on removing them, you just need to remove them in the content of each `genrex` column. And that is another question than the question you asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd

output = ["imdbPage", "title", "info", "Runtime(mins)", "releaseData", "imdbRating", "numberOfVotes",
          "numberOfEpisodes", "genre1_Action", "genre1_Adventure", "genre1_Animation", "genre1_Biography",
          "genre1_Comedy"]

print(pd.Series(data=output).str.replace('^genre\d+_', ''))
```

**Output**

```
0             imdbPage
1                title
2                 info
3        Runtime(mins)
4          releaseData
5           imdbRating
6        numberOfVotes
7     numberOfEpisodes
8               Action
9            Adventure
10           Animation
11           Biography
12              Comedy
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (reference [Here](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/03/how-to-change-column-names-and-row-indexes-in-pandas/)):

```
newcols = {}
for col in df.columns:
    newcol = re.match("(^genre\d{1,}_)(.*$)", col).group(2)
    newcols[col] = newcol
df.rename(columns=newcols, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

or, more concisely:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.match("(^genre\d{1,}-)(.*$)", x).group(2), inplace=True)
```